# How to exclude element from disabled fieldset in html

Tags: html, angularjs

How enable checkbox element which is disabled in fieldset with ng-disabled:

```
<fieldset data-ng-disabled="vm.isFundingAppDisabled()">
```

Checkbox code looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id=Checkbox_Legal_Person_Code 
name="Checkbox_Legal_Person_Code"> 
<label for="Checkbox_Legal_Person_Code" data-ng-if="vm.getFundingAppState() 
== 'SUBMITTED'&& vm.fundingApp.attributes.isTutoring"></label>
```

Is there a way to easily enable it without scripts?

Comment: Well, just make vm.isFundingAppDisabled() return false and it should be enabled. No?

Comment: Yes but i need all fields except checkboxes disabled in that fieldset. Doing that manually on all of them wouldnt be correct

Comment: Disabling `<fieldset>` disables all of its children. The HTML5 spec doesn't provide a way for a child element to "undisable" a disable setting inherited from a parent fieldset. For more information, see [MDN HTML Element Reference - `<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

Comment: ok, thank you. I did it manually on elements that needed to be disabled only. Problems like this occurs when you work on other teams project :D

Answer (score 0):

When the condition `vm.isFundingAppDisabled()` in `data-ng-disabled` becomes `false`, The checkbox will automatically be enabled..

Comment: Yes, but i need to keep check boxes enabled seperatly from that condition.

Comment: Adding disabled attribute  to fieldset makes non-sense. By the way, the parent tag contains disabled attribute, so the child would also be disabled untill the condition becomes false.

Comment: ok, thank you. I did it manually on elements that needed to be disabled only. Problems like this occurs when you work on other teams project :D